# Yaml key with "-" is not accepted in karate

Tags: karate

Working Scenario:

name.yml has the following,
firstName: step
lastName: curry

Given def data = read('name.yml')
And print data.firstName

able to get the value from yml file as expected

Issue:
name.yml has the following,
first-name: step
last-name: curry

Given def data = read('name.yml')
And print data.first-name

no value been fetched.